# Display running totals in SSRS in a shape of triangle for Los Development (Loss Triangle) report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, cumulative-sum

I need to make numbers cumulative total in a shape of triangle.

Vertical Month-Year is EffectiveDate
Horizontal Month-Year is LossDate

[image]

**Should be like this:**

[image]

Using SSRS Expression I am able to get cumulative :

```
=RunningValue(Fields!PolicyCount.Value, SUM, "TablixName")
```

But it gives me this:

[image]

How should I write my logic to eliminate number 11 in cell Feb-17

eliminate Apr-18 and so on? Basically to make it triangle?

Data sample:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you give me an advise what tool should I use to make sure it paste as numbers and not image? I used excel but it still inserts it as image

Comment: A [markdown table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), @Serdia .

Comment: Also, please make sure your sample data matches the expected results above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the scope of the RunningValue() expression

from this

```
=RunningValue(Fields!PolicyCount.Value, SUM, "TablixName")
```

to use the name of your RowGroup, not the name of the tablix.

In my test I called the Row Group EffRowGroup as you can see here..

[image]

So the Final expression looked like this..

```
=RunningValue(Fields!PolicyCount.Value, SUM, "EffRowGroup")
```

We do this so that the running value is only evaluated within the context of the row group.

Here are the results.

1. The base data
2. Your original expression
3. The final expression

[image]

Comment: OMG! I can't believe that was it!  Evaluating within row group totally makes sense. Thank you soooooo much Alan!

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted (check mark below the vote up/down buttons). This helps other users find answers to similar questions.